# should .pdb and .exe files be in the same folder and with same name

Tags: visual-studio-2010

""""""""""""""""""

0x000000004007537B (File and line number not available): MILI2Service.exe!(Function name unavailable)
    0x000000004009E4B6 (File and line number not available): MILI2Service.exe!(Function name unavailable)
    0x000000004009C3B9 (File and line number not available): MILI2Service.exe!(Function name unavailable)
    0x0000000040105D9B (File and line number not available): MILI2Service.exe!(Function name unavailable)
    0x0000000040106496 (File and line number not available): MILI2Service.exe!(Function name unavailable)
    0x000000003990BAA1 (File and line number not available): sechost.dll!QueryServiceDynamicInformation + 0x1C1 bytes
    0x000000003A5B167E (File and line number not available): KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x1A bytes
    0x000000003AD6C3F1 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21 bytes
  Data:
    A0 47 6F 01    00 00 00 00    20 4F 6F 01    00 00 00 00     .Go..... .Oo.....
    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    01 00 00 00     ........ ........
    10 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    7F 4B 00 00    FD FD FD FD     ........ .K......
    01 00 00 00    01 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     ........ ........
    FD FD FD FD                                                  ........ ........

Visual Leak Detector detected 71 memory leaks (14423 bytes).
Largest number used: 2809845 bytes.
Total allocations: 275235091 bytes.
Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
The program '[0xB0] MILI2Service.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

The above output can be verified.I have set Generate Debug info to Yes (Project->properties->linker->debugging).This application is running on different windows machine(windows server 2012) and iam debugging the code using Visual Leak detector i.e., project source code in windows 7.am'I missing something......

after creating my executable(target2.exe), i have created pdb file(target.pdb).and these files are created in different folders.but i can see (File and line number not available) and (Function name unavailable) flooding . Is that .exe and .pdb should have same name ? Should they be present in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug code outside your project source code, such as the Windows or third-party code your project calls, you have to specify the location of the .pdb (and optionally, the source files of the external code) and those files need to exactly match the build of the executables.

Comment: yes debugging the code outside project source code.But in my project executable is created as(target_2.exe) and pdb file is created as (target.pdb) and they are created in different folders.Is this valid?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that .exe and .pdb should have same name ?

Yes, please use the same name.

> Should they be present in the same folder.

It depends on your IDE enviroment, in Windbg and Visual sutdio, you may find some place to set your symbol file path.

I suppose you are using visual studio 2010, my tool is Visual Studio 2008, in "Tool"->"Option", you will find in "Debugging" tab, there is "Symbols", where you can set the symbol file path, and you can also download public symbols of M$ exe files from Microsoft symbol servers also. I think Visual studio 2010 also have this feature, you may check it.